# Jsoup dose not parse title tag correctly

Tags: jsoup

I have an example html document, when I use Jsoup to parse it, I find title tag is parsed as child node of body tag instead of head tag by mistake. Is it a bug?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s= FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(Test.class.getResource("test.html").getFile()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Document doc= Jsoup.parse(s);
        System.out.println(doc.select("body > title").first());
        System.out.println(doc.select("head > title").first());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the code above but with a modification:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n" +
                "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n" +
                "<head>\n" +
                "  <title>404</title>\n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>\n";

        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
        System.out.println(document.select("head > title").text());
        System.out.println(document.select("title").text());
        System.out.println(document.select("body > title").text());
    }
}
```

Here I define a String called "html", and I initialize it with the HTML code you shared via OneDrive and it works as expected. If you select the head tag and then the nested title tag it prints 404 and so on if you just select the title tag. But if you try to select the body tag and then the nested title tag it just prints blank, because it does not exists.

The error you are having I guess it is because the HTML import method, because it modifies its structure or the read of the document is wrong. So check that piece of code and consider it replacing it:

```
String s = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(Test.class.getResource("test.html").getFile()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

To solve your problem in this particular case you can just select the title tag, because it is going to be unique in the whole HTML. JSOUP selection does not need you to select every element from the top until the element you really want to select, you can select it directly if it has any kind of identifier.

If you need anything related to the CSS selection of JSOUP,  take a look at [JSOUP CSS Selection Syntax examples](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Hope this helped you! If you need anything else feel free to ask!

Comment: I guess it is because of BOM of the UTF-8 encoded html document. I change the BOM to a space when debugging and then Jsoup works as expected.